# Extract unit test results from multi-stage Docker build (.NET Core 2.0)

Tags: unit-testing, dockerfile, asp.net-core-2.0

I am building a .NET Core 2.0 web API and I am creating a Docker image. I am quite new to Docker so apologies if the question has been answered before.

I have the following Docker file for creating the image. In particular, I run the unit tests during the build process and the results are output to `./test/test_results.xml` (in a temporary container created during the build, I guess). My question is, how do I access these test results after the build has finished?

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env

WORKDIR /app

# Copy main csproj file for DataService
COPY src/DataService.csproj ./src/
RUN dotnet restore ./src/DataService.csproj

# Copy test csproj file for DataService
COPY test/DataService.Tests.csproj ./test/
RUN dotnet restore ./test/DataService.Tests.csproj

# Copy everything else (excluding elements in dockerignore)
COPY . ./

# Run the unit tests
RUN dotnet test --results-directory ./ --logger "trx;LogFileName=test_results.xml" ./test/DataService.Tests.csproj

# Publish the app to the out directory
RUN dotnet publish ./src/DataService.csproj -c Release -o out

# Build the runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5001
COPY --from=build-env /app/src/out .

# Copy test results to the final image as well??
# COPY --from=build-env /app/test/test_results.xml .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DataService.dll"]
```

One approach that I have taken is to comment in the line `# COPY --from=build-env /app/test/test_results.xml .`. This puts the `test_results.xml` in my final image. I can then extract these results and remove the `test_results.xml` from the final image using the following powershell script.

```
$id=$(docker create dataservice)
docker cp ${id}:app/test_results.xml ./test/test_results.xml
docker start $id
docker exec $id rm -rf /app/test_results.xml
docker commit $id dataservice
docker rm -vf $id
```

This however seems ugly and I am wondering is there a cleaner way to do it.

I was hoping that there was a way to mount a volume during `docker build` but it does not appear that this is going to be supported in the official Docker.

I am looking now at creating a separate image, solely for the unit tests.

Not sure if there is a recommended way of achieving what I want.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am running into the exact same problem.

Comment: @Mike No, sorry, not yet. I have just gone with the approach I mentioned of adding the test results temporarily to the final image and extracting them. Quite new to Docker so I just wanted to check if there were other ways of doing this or a recommended way.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for your question - I needed to solve the same thing.

I added a separate container stage based on results of the build. The tests and its output are all handled in there so they never reach the final container. So build-env is used to build and then an intermediate test container is based on that build-env image and final is based on runtime container with results of build-env copied in.

```
# ---- Test ----
# run tests and capture results for later use. This use the results of the build stage
FROM build AS test
#Use label so we can later obtain this container from the multi-stage build
LABEL test=true
WORKDIR /
#Store test results in a file that we will later extract 
RUN dotnet test --results-directory ../../TestResults/ --logger "trx;LogFileName=test_results.xml" "./src/ProjectNameTests/ProjectNameTests.csproj"
```

I added a shell script as a next step that then tags the image as project-test.

```
#!bin/bash
id=`docker images --filter "label=test=true"  -q`
docker tag $id projectname-test:latest
```

After that, I basically do what you do which is use docker cp and get the file out. The difference is my test results were never in the final image so I don't touch the final image.

Overall I think the correct way to handle tests is probably create a test image (based on the build image) and run it with a mounted volume for test results and have it run the unit tests when that container starts. Having a proper image/container would also allow you to run integration tests etc. This article is older but details similar https://blogs.infosupport.com/build-deploy-test-aspnetcore-docker-linux-tfs2015/

Comment: Too bad, that there is no simple way, but your label is a nice idea!

Comment: The same idea is described here: https://medium.com/@cyril.delmas/how-to-keep-the-build-reports-with-a-docker-multi-stage-build-on-jenkins-507200f4007f

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I ended up here looking for the same thing so will drop my tuppence worth in here for posterity!

Nowadays you can use `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` to make docker use buildkit to build your images, which is quicker and caches better, and has an `--output` option which solves this problem for you. I've got a golang-based example below, but this should work equally well for pretty much anything.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM golang:1.17 as deps
WORKDIR /src

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY command ./command
COPY internal ./internal

# Tests

FROM deps as test
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache go test -v ./... 2>&1 | tee unit.out

FROM scratch as test-output
COPY --from=test /src/unit.out /unit.out

# Build

FROM deps as build
RUN your build steps
```

This dockerfile has a bunch of stages:

1. copy across requirements spec and install dependencies (for caching)
2. run your tests (re-use `deps` stage to avoid repeating ourselves)
3. copy your test results to a scratch image
4. build your image / binary / whatever you'd normally do from `deps`

Now if you set `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` somewhere and run:

```
docker build
```

then docker builds your code / image but DOES NOT RUN THE TESTS! Because your `build` stage isn't linked to the `test` stage at all it bypasses both test stages entirely. However, you can now use the `--target` option to select the `test-output` build stage and the `--output` option to tell it where on your local disk to copy the result:

```
docker build --target test-output --output results .
```

Docker will then build the dependencies (or re-use the cache from the image build if you did that first), run your tests and copy the contents of your scratch image (i.e. your test report) into the `results` directory. Job done. :)

Edit:

An article using this approach with a .NET app and explaining the whole thing a bit better! https://kevsoft.net/2021/08/09/exporting-unit-test-results-from-a-multi-stage-docker-build.html