# How can i display the result of Nunit from a windows container to TeamCity?

Tags: docker, nunit, teamcity, nunit-console

I'm building a .net application in a windows container from TeamCity. I have installed on the docker image NUnit3-Console. I want to display the result of NUnit during the build on the tab Test on Teamcity like if i was building from teamcity.

The build step completed successfully but i am unable to see "tests" tab on the build.

How can I dot that?

Thanks.

Comment: would this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705781/extract-unit-test-results-from-multi-stage-docker-build-net-core-2-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the parameter --teamcity to NUnit3-Console. it will format the result to Teamcity and the "test" tab will appear.